# Taking user information that is stored in another table (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel project, and I need to take logged in user information that is stored in another table.

I have tried using Eloquent, but no luck. This is the example.

I have a `User` model that connects to a `Login` table:

```
public function LoginInfo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\LoginInfoModel', 'infoID');
}
```

And a `LoginInfoModel`, with this connection:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','UserID');
}
```

But by outputting `Auth::user()`, there is no info from `LoginInfo` table.

Any suggestions or maybe this can be done not using Eloquent?

Thanks

Comment: I find my mistake, I didn't get that building relationships between two models, I should mention the foreign key of second table, not his one key. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` is just an instance of the User model, so if you have the LogInfo Relationship on the User model you can simply do:

```
Auth::user()->LoginInfo()
```

Comment: I have an error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

If you call the relation on the User object you will retrieve that information.

`Auth::user()->LoginInfo`

As written in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

> The first argument passed to the hasOne method is the name of the related model. Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model: